in vb.net "Await httpClient.GetAsync" does not wait for response
I have the following code
Public Class NfonService

  Public Async Function GetApiVersionAsync() As Task(Of Object)
     Debug.Print(0)
     Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(BASE_URI & "/api/version")
     Debug.Print(1)
     Dim responseContent As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
     Debug.Print("Result2:" & responseContent)
     Return responseContent
  End Function

End Class


Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Dim MyNfonService As New NfonService
     Dim s As String
     Debug.Print("a")
     s = MyNfonService.GetApiVersionAsync().ToString
     Debug.Print("Result1:" & s)
     Debug.Print("b")
   End Sub

End Class

I would expect the debug outputs to be in the following order
a
0
1
Result2: (some reasonable response text)
Result1: (same response text)
b

I AM getting
a
0
Result1: (nothing)
b
1
Result2: (some reasonable response text)

Shouldn't Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(BASE_URI & "/api/version") wait for the httpClient.GetAsync to return a response before continueing? What am I missing?

Your expectations are wrong. You are not awaiting in s = MyNfonService.GetApiVersionAsync().ToString. Thut Form1_Load continues its synchronous running when the first async call in GetApiVersionAsync happens.  GetApiVersionAsync runs asynchronously in the background and prints its results after it finishes

I see your point. If I do s = MyNfonService.GetApiVersionAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString I get the debug outputs a and 0 and then nothing at all anymore.

use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() after GetAsync()
like this
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(BASE_URI & "/api/version").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

If I do that, vb.net throws BC36930 'Await' requires that the type 'HttpResponseMessage' have a suitable GetAwaiter method.

remove Await keyword and try again

Thank you! That worked exactly as expected. For others, these are the two lines that make the code work: Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(BASE_URI & "/api/version").GetAwaiter().GetResult() and s = MyNfonService.GetApiVersionAsync().GetAwaiter.GetResult

No, do not  use GetResult.  Use Await, that's what it's for.  Especially if there is UI, GetResult is likely to deadlock at some point.

GetAPIVersionAsync returns Task(Of Object) which is a representation of the ongoing (asynchronous) work.  I would expect that running ToString on that task would return either "Task" or "Task`1" or the like.
The correct way to work asynchronously is to use Await to return control to the user interface while the asynchronous work is proceeding.  When the result is available, the routine will resume immediately after the Await expression.
Although it is usually recommended not to use Async Sub, there is a specific exception for event handlers.  So you should be doing something like this:
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load)
        Dim MyNfonService As New NfonService
        Debug.Print("a")
        Dim s = (Await MyNfonService.GetApiVersionAsync()).ToString
        Debug.Print("Result1:" & s)
        Debug.Print("b")
    End Sub
End Class

Note the use of Await.
You should not use GetResult except in very specific cases which do not appear to apply here.
I'd strongly recommend to read everything Stephen Cleary has written on asynchronous code.
